# Is the following definition an equivalent definition of continuity of a function

Tags: continuity, definition

Let $f:(0,1) \to \mathbb{R}$ be a given function.

Definition: for any $\epsilon \gt 0$, there exists $\delta \gt 0$ such that for all $x \in (0,1)$ and $|x-x_0| \leq \delta$, one has $|f(x) - f(x_0)| \leq \epsilon$ .

I think its equivalent to the definition of continuity because it doesn't matter if it's $\lt$ or $\leq$.

Comment: This is just continuity at $x_{0}$ though.

Comment: Yes, the strict vs. non-strict inequalities won't matter for this concept. If a function satisfies your definition, find a corresponding $(\epsilon_0,\delta_0)$ pair. Then for any $\epsilon_1>\epsilon_0$ you may take any $\delta_1<\delta_0$ in the traditional definition of continuity. The other direction is of course similar.

Comment: If I understand correctly, you're asking if the definition holds for weak inequality aswell. In the case of continuity it doesn`t matter, Becasue you can always take $\epsilon<\epsilon'$ and have a strong inequality (Since you can take any $\epsilon$)